# Give a Index Name to associative array codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, associative-array

I am using a associative array to store data but i use associative array inside a another associative array my code  like this

```
$field2 = array();

        for ($i = 0; $i < $numberofFilreds; $i++) {

            $fname = $this->input->post('mytext' . $i);

            array_push($field2, $fname = array(
                'type' => $this->input->post('DataTypes' . $i),
                'null' => TRUE,
            ));
        }
```

and when i run my code i get the array like this

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["type"]=> string(4) "text" ["null"]=> bool(true) } }
```

the thing is i want `[0]=> array(2)` like this `["Name"]=> array(2)` i have no idea how to do it please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So simply use `$field2["Name"] = array(...)`. replace the `Name` with your unique index.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $numberofFilreds; $i++) {
    $fname = $this->input->post('mytext' . $i);
    $field2[$fname] = array(
        'type' => $this->input->post('DataTypes' . $i),
        'null' => TRUE,
    ));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i am still learning php, thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

If your `$fname` var is unique, use like this:

```
$fname = $this->input->post('mytext' . $i);
$$field2[$fname] = array(
        'type' => $this->input->post('DataTypes' . $i),
        'null' => TRUE,
    );
```

Comment: Thanx for the help :) ur answer and the answer that Hashem Qolami gives is same so thank you very much for your effort